# Can't pass HTML Collection as a parameter in Js function?

Tags: javascript, function, htmlcollection

I've been following a slideshow tutorial on w3schools to learn how to create my own.

This is the link to the tutorial's [code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto). What I am referring to is this code however.

```
<script>
  var slideIndex = 0;
  showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = 
document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style.display = "none";  
}
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" 
active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 
2 seconds
}
</script>
```

I wanted to make multiple slideshows for a single page so I made it so this section of the code would take a parameter and then I could just insert my list of images. But when I changed the code to this...

```
 var images = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var imageNum = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

showSlides(images, imageNum);

function showSlides(slides, dots) {
    var i;

for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style.display = "none";  
}
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";

    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
}
```

Complete [code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/6zrz917qww) available via this link.

It gives me the error property of length undefined, even though .length can be used on a HTML Collection.

Why does it seem that this function cannot accept a HTML Collection as a parameter?

**Edit:** After looking at feedback and noticing that I made it harder for people to help me, I made a codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/6zrz917qww) with my issue. I included the solution as a comment, so people can see before and after. I also included the entire function above.

Thank you for your feedback so I can make questions more clear and sorry about the trouble!

Comment: Can we see the entire function for the new showSlides?

Comment: You should create a [mcve] with a live demo (there is a button for live demos in the editor toolbar). It makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Please click `<>`, add a [mcve] using placeholder.com or lorempixel.com

Comment: well is `getElementsByClassName` actually finding anything?

Comment: @epascarello even if it found nothing it would still return an `HTMLCollection` with a length of `0`

Comment: I'm so sorry guys this is my first time posting, I will be sure to include the entire function next time.

I made a codesandbox with the new code. I will include it in an edit. Thank you for your feedback so I can make it easier for all of you next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of that line at the end of the function

```
setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
```

it call `showSlides` without any arguments

To add argument to call you can do :

```
setTimeout(() => { showSlides(slides, dots) }, 2000);
// call from an anonymous function

// or

setTimeout(showSlides, 2000, slides, dots); 
// use additional params of setTimeout
```

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) the doc for `setTimeout`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had a quick question to make sure I understand completely.

Since the argument was needed in the setTimeout portion of the function that was the only reason that the code said "slides" was undefined?